# django multiple query filter - match 1 or 2 fields

Tags: django, filter, field, match

I have a model like this:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=800)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rank = models.BigIntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Risultati"

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categorie"
```

and views:

```
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search.html')

def result(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        results = Result.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[q], desc__icontains=q).order_by('-rank')
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results, 'query': q})
    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'error': True})

def detail(request, result_id):
    try:
        result = Result.objects.get(pk=result_id)
    except Result.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Nessun risultato :(")
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'result': result})
```

i need to search by filter, tags OR desc, I try to concatenate the filter().filter() but nothing happen, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining expressions either in the same `filter()` or in separate ones performs an implicit `AND`. If you want to perform an `OR` or an explicit `AND` then you need to use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) instead.

```
....filter(Q(tags__name__in=[q]) | Q(desc__icontains=q))....
```